# Rigify Finger assigned to different parent

Tags: rigging, rigify

I am having a problem with the rigify addon. After I generate the rig, everything works perfectly except the finger bone `f_middle.01.L` (it doesn't respond to the movement of the `hand_ik.L`), although the same bone for the right hand works fine. I have looked for differences between the two bones and have found that the parent is set to "root" for the left finger bone (the one not working), as opposed to the right finger bones parent being `ORG-palm.02.R`.
After realizing this I thought I could just change the parent of the bone, but unfortunately access is disabled.

I would prefer to be able to solve this issue without generating the rig again if possible because I have already made a few poses in the pose library, but if it can't be avoided then so be it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, autorun Python scripts were already enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The access is disabled simply because you're in pose mode: select the armature, go to edit mode and change the parent from "root" to "ORG-palm.02.L".

Remember also that if you save your file and create a new one, generating a brand new rig, you can import from the old file your pose library: you will find it under the "action" folder.